# fsck not working over disk

Tags: boot, fsck

Hello I'm trying to exit linux emergency mode after a bad reboot of my system,

First I checked `/etc/fstab` and got that the following partition has troubles:

```
UUID=0C80015D80014EA0 /mnt/data ntfs deafults 0 2
```

the `2` number here appoints that a certain file system needs to be checked.

Looking at `sudo blkid` output, that UUID appoints to my `/dev/sdb1` file, so I got to the conclusion that this file is corrupted, I've been reading some threads that suggests to check and repair a corrupted partition using `fsck`, but when I run `fsck /dev/sdb1` I got the following message:

```
fsck of util-linux 2.36
```

I thought that maybe `fsck` was not working well but when I tried the command over my `/root` partition, it worked well:

```
~# sudo fsck /dev/sdb3
fsck of util-linux 2.36
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
/dev/sdb3 its mounted
```

So what can I do ?

When I run `df -h` the `/dev/sdb1` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of multiple things here.

- /etc/fstab is a static file and the field you have highlighted does *not* indicate the status of the filesystem, but the potential order it might be checked
- The line you have selected says the filesystem is of type ntfs, which is a windows filesystem.  Only windows can check this filesystem, linux fsck does not support it.
- When fsck exits with no errors, that means it found no errors.  The line you have quoted just shows fsck giving its version number, it neither indicates an error or that it did anything about checking anything
- When fsck complains that a filesystem is mounted, it is telling you that you can't run fsck on a filesystem that is in use and writable.  Additionally, if the filesystem was able to be mounted writable, likely there is nothing wrong with it and doesn't need fsck anyway.

It is unclear from your question what the real problem is, because you did not include any errors, which would have been printed shortly before it went into emergency mode.

At a guess, `/dev/sdb1` is probably not mounted because the filesystem is corrupt and needs to be checked (by windows), and the system is in emergency mode because it was unable to mount a filesystem required in fstab.

It is ill advised to mount windows filesystems directly in fstab, since linux can't repair them.  I would suggest either adding `noauto` to the options for sdb1 in fstab (i.e., `defaults,noauto`) and manually mounting it later, or use automount or udisks-daemon to automatically mount it after boot when it is needed.

Of these, automount is probably the better option, because it will also automatically unmount it when it is no longer needed, and it is likely that the filesystem will be corrupted if it is still mounted if the system is suddenly rebooted without properly shutting down linux.